How to do evaluation of Hector SLAM mapping, without ground truth map
I am doing my thesis and professor is asking me to do the scientific evaluation of hector SLAM algorithm. I can create the map of the room but as i dont have the ground truth map available of the room. so how can i do evaluation of the maps generated by it to identify the best map.And what are the things i have to look after. i am using 2D lidar for it. i also have camera which is unused in my robot.
please help me!

Well, for more simplistic maps, such as rooms where the most definable features are walls and possibly desks / countertops, it may be possible to use a laser rangefinder to manually dimension the room at the level of your scanner. Then use those measurements and a CAD software of your choice to create a map / drawing of the room(s).
For this method, I would stick to rooms without much clutter, such as chair legs, table legs, boxes ect that would be difficult to measure and draw.

In your case, I recommend performing an end-to-end evaluation, such as done in this paper due to the absence of ground truth poses. Keep in mind that SLAM methods are typically assessed based on the accuracy of the calculated poses rather than the map accuracy, although both are closely related.
Here’s a straightforward approach: Start by acquiring a map from a known initial position and orientation of the sensor. Move the sensor through the environment and then return to the original position and orientation to stop data acquisition. This way, you can easily calculate the offset in terms of 2D position (X, Y) and orientation (yaw angle in 2D). This method allows for an easy evaluation of the pose accuracy throughout the data collection because you know that the pose at the end should be exactly the same as at the beginning; the difference is then the error of your SLAM system.
If you would like to have more dense points for evaluation, you may use your camera and fiducial markers on the ceiling, as done here. However, this is a more complex and time-consuming process since you need to locate them in known positions and detect them with the camera, which should be well-calibrated with the LiDAR sensor. For more (costly) alternatives, you can have a look at this post.
If you still wanna calculate the differences between maps, you can use metrics such as the Map Mean Entropy (MME), Mean Plane Variance (MPV), and the Nearest Neighbor Distance (NND), see explanation here. However, for that, you need the ground truth floor plan or a way to recreate it, as explained in Ethan's answer.
